# form button not recognising function

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML file with a basic form. I am calling a function on button click, but on click I receive "function is not defined". Everything appears to be in order vis-a-vis pointing to files, so I'm not sure where the disconnect is.
This is the layout:

[image: dir layout]

and these are my `index.html` and `main.js`, respectively:

```html
<!--index.html-->
  <form action="" method="get" class="form">
    <label for="form-input">Paste Key Here: </label>
    <input type="text" name="Key Input" id="form-input">
    <button id="form-button" type="button" onclick="GWAPIUser()">Click Here!</button>

    <script type="application/javascript;charset=utf-8" src="/public/javascripts/main.js"></script>
  </form>
```

```js
/* main.js */
const key = 'authkey';

async function GWAPIUser() {
  
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account/achievements?access_token=${key}`);
  const data = await response.json();

  console.log(data);
};
```

Directory was made with `express-generator`. This is my first time using it, so I'm not sure if that means anything.

Finally, this is the error I receive:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: GWAPIUser is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (?Key+Input=:18)`

Comment: @Andy — The return value is ignored by the event listener. That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not like `application/javascript;charset=utf-8` as a value for the `type` attribute.

"Non-modular JavaScript" is the default type for a `script` so you should **omit the `type` attribute** entirely in this case. Only include it if you need to specify `type="module"` or as a hack to store data in an element without rendering it.

```
<script src="/public/javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: hmm okay. So the issue is, if I don't have that, because of whatever wizardry goes on in Express, it doesn't like it. Is there a way to find common ground or will I not be able to use express-generator?

Comment: Your type attribute prevents the browser from requesting the script. If removing it doesn't fix the problem then you had multiple problems with the same symptoms an removing it has reduced the number of problems you have by one. If it still isn't working you need to do some more debugging. I'd start with the Network tab in the browser's developer tools and check to see what URL is being requested and what response you get back for it. (That is assuming that you aren't getting a different error now)

Comment: If I remove it, I get this: `The resource from “http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). localhost:3000`

Comment: And what do you get if you visit `http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/main.js` directly in the browser? Odds are that it is an HTML document, like the error says, which means the URL is wrong. It's possible it is the JS source code with the wrong content-type, but that's less likely (and needs the content type fixing **server-side** and not in the browser)

Comment: `Cannot GET /public/javascripts/main.js` I will root around in the auto-generated files

Comment: That's the 404 error. It isn't hitting any file.